# Get all json files from node folder and find specific attr inside

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

i've folder in my node app with several json files (can be more then 10 ) and I need from validation aspects to read them and find specific property and if this property occur in more than one json file throw an error,what is the best way to do it from **performance and efficiency aspects**

for example my folder called plugins
and all the json are built like following

**json1**

```
{
  "action": [
    {
      "delete": {
        "path": "deleteFile",
         "providedAction":"Del" 
      },
    {
      "update": {
        "path": "updateFile",
         "providedAction":"UPD" 
      }

    }
  ]
}
```

this is **valid json** since **providedAction = add is not exist** in other json **

**json2**

```
{
  "action": [
    {
      "add": {
        "path": "addFile",
         "providedAction":"Add" 
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

this is **not valid** json since **providedAction = UPD the action is already** exist
JSON 3

```
{
      "action": [
        {
                  {
          "update": {
            "path": "updateFile",
             "providedAction":"UPD" 
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

I need to verify that just this json have the action "Del",if more than one json have this trow error,how its recommended to do it?

Comment: How large are the JSON files?

Comment: @RafaelNogueira- not to much lets say can have 50 line max of each file...

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about performance then. Do you need to search the JSONs or will this _always_ be at action[n].delete.action?

Comment: @RafaelNogueira- Thanks,so how would you do it,can you provide example as answer,thanks in advance!

Comment: No worries. I am working on it, but I need an answer to my last question ;-)

Comment: @RafaelNogueira-Thank you! the actions can be delete add update etc it can be anything but the structure is the same for every json file with action array and inside the array I need to verify that action with the same name are not exist in more then one json file,i'll edit my post now to make it clearer ...

Comment: @RafaelNogueira - i've edit my post to make it more clear:)

Comment: do you want to do something when a json is valid or invalid?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, here is the code. If you don't understand something let me know and I will glad to help you!

```
var glob = require("glob");
var fs = require("fs");

var _inArray = function(needle, haystack) {
  for(var k in haystack) {
    if(haystack[k] === needle) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

glob("json/*.json", function(err, files) { // read the folder or folders if you want: example json/**/*.json
  if(err) {
    console.log("cannot read the folder, something goes wrong with glob", err);
  }
  var matters = [];
  files.forEach(function(file) {
    fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err, data) { // Read each file
      if(err) {
        console.log("cannot read the file, something goes wrong with the file", err);
      }
      var obj = JSON.parse(data);
      obj.action.forEach(function(crud) {
        for(var k in crud) {
          if(_inArray(crud[k].providedAction, matters)) {
            // do your magic HERE
            console.log("duplicate founded!");
            // you want to return here and cut the flow, there is no point in keep reading files.
            break;
          }
          matters.push(crud[k].providedAction);
        }
      })
    });
  });
});
```

JSON 1:

```
{"action": [
  {
    "delete": {
      "path": "deleteFile",
      "providedAction": "Del"
    }
  },
  {
    "update": {
      "path": "updateFile",
      "providedAction": "UPD"
    }
  }
]
}
```

JSON 2:

```
{
  "action": [
    {
      "add": {
        "path": "addFile",
        "providedAction": "Add"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

JSON 3:

```
{
  "action": [
    {
      "update": {
        "path": "updateFile",
        "providedAction": "UPD"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not the prettiest code I've written, but here it is:

```
// Require the nodejs file system library
var fs = require('fs');
var path = '/usr/local/var/jsons';
var delCounter = 0;

// Readdir reads a path and gives an array of filenames
// to the callback handleFiles.
fs.readdir(path, handleFiles);

function handleFiles (err, files) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var i;
    var jsonFilePattern=/\.[json]+$/i;
    var fileName;
    var filePath;
    // Tells fs to read an utf-8 file.
    var fileReadOptions = {
        'encoding':'utf-8'
    };

    for (i = 0; i < files.length; ++i) {
        fileName = files[i];
        // Check if the file has a .json extension
        if (fileName.match(jsonFilePattern)) {
            filePath = path + '/' + fileName;
            // Open the file as utf-8 and call handleJsonFile back
            // when done reading.
            fs.readFile(filePath, fileReadOptions, handleJsonFile);
        }
    }
}

function handleJsonFile (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dataObject = JSON.parse(data);
    var i;
    var action;
    // Loop through all possible action.
    for (i = 0; i < dataObject.action.length; ++i) {
        action = dataObject.action[i];
        if (action.delete &&
            action.delete.providedAction && 
            action.delete.providedAction === 'Del')
        {
            // If there is a 'Del', add it to the counter.
            ++delCounter;
        }
    }
    if (delCounter > 1) {
        throw new Exception('Jsons  not valid.');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! lets assume that I want to use glob I need to use only handleJsonFIle ? lets assume that I dont know the name of the 'Del' i.e. the  value I just want to verify that there is not more than one provide action how would you do that?Thanks in advance sir!

Comment: I'm not familiar with glob, but judging from @Lkzwieder 's answer, you could use handleJsonFile as callback to the second forEach. If you want to be sure that there is max. 1 occurence of each providedAction value, you would have to store the values, and each time you loop through the actions, verify that it isn't already stored.

Comment: I refael,Can you please provide example where is the best place and way to store this value inside the handleJsonFile...Thanks sir

Comment: Hi people!, what you do with glob is to select all js files in the path/s you want.. then you need to get all jsons inside. And then check those jsons.

If you read those jsons like Rafael does, you have to use `JSON.parse` to transform text to a json object. And then check the key you want. So, 1- get the files with glob (or do yourself), 2- read those files, 3-  convert to json, 4- check the keys. 5- Be happy.

Comment: @Lkzwieder -I've looked at your example but the problem is that you use hardcoded del and I want just to verify for duplicate if any...

Comment: That is because I was sleepy (and I still are), and coudn't understand you :P let me read again. I will help you, so... a couple of questions.
Can you choose the json format?, do you always have this structure in the json, I mean an object with `action` field, an array inside and that array could have `delete`, `update` and `add`??? and inside delete|add|update you always have path and providedAction???

Comment: Thanks what do you mean by json format ?I have exactly the same structure for all the json ,path and providerAction are the keys and should be exist in all the json files,the values can be change like "add" "upd" etc and I want just to verify that providerAction value are not exist in more than one json file its like a "key" if I found for example like my post the json3 have upd and also json1 throw an error...thanks sir for support!

Comment: Ok, let me a few minutes, and I will post the solution to your problem. But, my advice, try to implement only what you can understand so, ask questions about the code if you dont get it :P

Comment: I'm curious about your `/\.[json]+$/i` pattern.  That would match files like `foo.jjjj` or `bar.nosj`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps?, enjoy!!!
`npm install glob`

JSON 1

```
module.exports = {
  "action": [{
    "delete": {
      "path": "deleteFile",
      "action":"Del"
    }
  }]
}
```

CODE

```
(function() {
  var glob = require("glob");
  glob("path/to/*.js", function(er, files) {
    if(er) return;
    var x = 0;
    files.forEach(function(file) {
      require(file)['action'].forEach(function(act) {
        if(act.delete.action && act.delete.action == "Del") x++;
      });
    });
    if(x > 1) throw new Exception(""); // or something ja!
  });
})();
```

5am without sleep, sorry if I commit mistakes, I want to show you the way only... not for copy paste!! xD.

Answer (score 1):

Using modern syntax, reduce and spread could be of great help here:

```
const files = readdirSync(path);
files.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const file = JSON.parse(readFileSync(path.join(path, curr), 'utf8'));
  const merged = { ...acc, ...file };

  // Check for destructive merging.
  if (Object.keys(file).length + Object.keys(acc).length > Object.keys(merged).length) {
    throw Error('Destructive merge of JSON files.');
  }

  return merged;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

// dir path that contains all your json file
const dirPath = './something/something';

const files = fs.readdirSync(dirPath);

const arr = []
files.forEach((val, i) => {
    const file = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(dirPath, val), 'utf8'));
    arr.push(file);
})

if (arr.length === files.length) {
    console.log(arr)
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).